# Formatting cox data with time-dependent continuous variables and unequal time intervals

Tags: r, survival, repeated-measures, time-varying-covariate, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I am planning to do a joint model for longitudinal and survival data, with multiple time-dependent/time-varying continuous variables.

However, I am having trouble re-formatting my dataset to be in a long format.

My data currently includes the following relevant variables:

- Study ID
- Follow up A – Number of days to the first assessment follow up from baseline
- Follow up B – Number of days to the second assessment follow up from
  baseline
- Follow up C - Number of days to the first assessment follow up from
  baseline
- Follow up D - Number of days to the first assessment follow up from
  baseline
- First infection – Number of days to infection
- Status – Status if ever infected during study (0 if no infection, 1
  if infection during study)
- Follow up A treatment score – Continuous, from 0 to 5
- Follow up B treatment score – Continuous, from 0 to 5
- Follow up C treatment score – Continuous, from 0 to 5
- Follow up D treatment score – Continuous, from 0 to 5

I have looked at the timedep vignette and other sources on here, but I am still unsure of how I can convert my data to the required long format where there is a separate row for each time interval for each participant.

Currently, as you can see, each subject has one row of information for all follow ups. I would like to make it so that each subject’s follow up time interval (A through D) is its own row and has its own treatment score (A through D).

Additionally, while some subjects get infections during the study, we still have some of their treatment scores from later follow ups after the infection date. For example, a subject may have 30, 67, 90, and 105 days for their follow ups A through D respectively, and have different treatment scores, but their infection date might have occurred on day 50.

Is there a way to restructure my data for this?